# Merge ACS Commons Reports AEM

Tags: adobe, aem, jcr, jcr-sql2

I have multiple queries in JCR-SQL2 and are currently separated in multiple ACS commons reports. This is not very user friendly as we need to go through different reports to look for the data. I was wondering if there's any way to merge these reports into one?

Comment: Probably you will need custom code to produce the single report after processing the different result sets and output a CSV file with the matching entries.